# How to copy the Data form the Specified address and copy it to the next specified location using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet which contains the details of the each product.

[image]

Here i have crested a button (ADD), by clicking on it i want to copy all the details of the CONTROL POWER TRANSFORMERS block and copy it to below (i mean copy it from B20).

I have written a code to pinpoint the CTPT (which is the unique id for that product) keeping it as a reference i have copied whole block till the row ends using the below code.

```
Set cF = .Find(what:="CTPT", _
    lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

num = cF.Address ' Here we will the get the cell address of CTPT ($A$14)
            WsEPC.Range(cF.Offset(-1, 3), cF.Offset(-1, 1).End(xlDown)).Copy
```

Now while pasting the cell i need to do couple of things

1. I need to insert an row by finding the cell address of the clicked button
2. Paste the copied Data

Code any one help me out in achieving these couple of task.
Any help is Appreciated!

Comment: (1) What is CTPT and why do you need it, where is it used, etc? (2) What exactly (more specifically than what you've said so far) do you want to copy and where do you want to paste it?

Comment: Can you explain "I need to insert an row by finding the cell address of the clicked button" a bit more plz? Do you meant to insert a row before the clicked button?

Comment: “CTPT” is the unique id which is maintained for each and every product. If I need to have one More copy of the similar product then these are the steps which I am following.
I will find the cell address of the “CTPT” and by keeping the reference of it I will copy all the parameters which belongs to that particular product.
Then I will select the cell address of the ADD button, by keeping the reference of it I will add one more row first and then I will insert the copied data by selecting the second column of the newly inserted row. Now I have the duplicate of the Product Details

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test_Karthik()
Dim WbEPC As Workbook, _
    WbCPT As Workbook, _
    WsEPC As Worksheet, _
    WsCPT As Worksheet, _
    FirstAddress As String, _
    WriteRow As Long, _
    cF As Range, _
    num As String

Set WbEPC = Workbooks("EPC 1.xlsx")
Set WbCPT = Workbooks("Control Power Transformers.xlsm")
Set WsEPC = WbEPC.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WsCPT = WbCPT.Sheets("Sheet2")

With WsEPC
    .Activate
    With .Range("A1:A10000")
    'First, define properly the Find method
        Set cF = .Find(What:="CTPT", _
                    After:=ActiveCell, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)

        'If there is a result, keep looking with FindNext method
        If Not cF Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = cF.Address
            Do
                num = cF.Address ' Here we will the get the cell address of CTPT ($A$14)
                WsEPC.Range(cF.Offset(0, 1).End(xlUp), cF.Offset(0, 3).End(xlDown)).Copy
                WriteRow = WsCPT.Range("E" & WsCPT.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                WsCPT.Range("E" & WriteRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

                cF.EntireRow.Insert xlDown, False


                Set cF = .FindNext(cF)
            'Look until you find again the first result
            Loop While Not cF Is Nothing And cF.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @R3uK, experimented with my code by doing some slight modification and it worked, i have posted the code below

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()




Dim WbEPC As Workbook, _
WbCPT As Workbook, _
WsEPC As Worksheet, _
WsCPT As Worksheet, _
FirstAddress As String, _
WriteRow As Long, _
cF As Range, _
num As String

Set WbEPC = Workbooks("EPC 1.xlsm")
Set WbCPT = Workbooks("Control Power Transformers.xlsm")
Set WsEPC = WbEPC.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WsCPT = WbCPT.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim b As Object, RowNumber As Integer
Set b = ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton21")
With b.TopLeftCell
    RowNumber = .Row
End With


 Rows(RowNumber + 1 & ":" & RowNumber + 1).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove





    With WsEPC
    .Activate
    With .Range("A1:A10000")

Set cF = .Find(what:="CTPT", _
    lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            num = cF.Address ' Here we will the get the cell address of CTPT ($A$14)
            WsEPC.Range(cF.Offset(-1, 3), cF.Offset(-1, 1).End(xlDown)).Copy
            WsEPC.Range("B" & RowNumber + 1).Select


                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

End With
End With

MsgBox " Successfully added the product to EPC"


End Sub
```

Comment: For a code block this size you really need to add some kind of explanation as to what you've done and why.